# Как выводить последние 3 элемента из массива?

Tags: php

уважаемые знатоки!
У меня есть код:

```
@foreach($receivedBills as $bill)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$bill->created}}</td>
      <td>{{"{$bill->date_from->format('d.m.Y')} - {$bill->date_to->format('d.m.Y')}"}}</td>
      <td>{{$bill->cnt}}</td>
      <td>{{$bill->amount}}</td>
      <td>{{$bill->is_paid?'Оплачен':'Не оплачен'}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Он выводит все данные в таблицу, а мне нужно вывести только последние три, как мне это сделать?

Comment: не хотите это решить на уровне запроса к БД?

Comment: я с удовольствием, только мне надо научиться делать это..
это самый простой путь?

Comment: а вы простой путь ищите, или правильный? самый простой путь это сделать `array_slice($recievedBills, -3)` и его итерировать. Если нужен правильный путь, то надо разобраться что вы вообще делаете. Очевидно, если вым в целом из результата запроса нужны только последние 3 элемента, а остальные никогда не используются, то выбирать это остальное смысла нет.

Comment: я хочу выводить последние 3 элемента для дашборда, а вообще все в отдельную страницу

Comment: а как мне связать array_slice($recievedBills, -3) с верхним кодом?